# Delete button not functioning correctly on VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

On my page, I've got a table of rows.  At the bottom of the table I have an "Add Row" button, which works fine.  Each row has a "Delete" button, which should remove the row on the page immediately, and delete it from the database on "Save."  At the first delete, the page re-renders successfully, and removes the correct row.

However, the delete functionality begins acting very strange if I try to delete two rows (on the second "click" of a delete button); sometimes the wrong row is deleted from the page, and then a different row is deleted from the table.  I've tried every form of debugging I can, but cannot figure out what's going on.  I suspect it has something to do with a counter getting off with the second delete, but I'm not sure.  I'd really appreciate somebody giving thoughts on what I'm doing wrong.

Extension:

```
public with sharing class PayrollAuthorization_extn {

public list <PA_Distribution__c> PayrollDistributionList {get; set;}
public Payroll_Authorization__c PA;
public PA_Distribution__c del;
public String rowID {get;set;}
public List<PA_Distribution__c> delProgramList {get; set;} 


public PayrollAuthorization_extn(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

PA = (Payroll_Authorization__c)controller.getRecord();
PayrollDistributionList = [Select Id, Name, Program__r.Name, Program_Percent__c, Program_as_Number__c
        From PA_Distribution__c 
        Where Payroll_Authorization__r.id =: controller.getId()
        ];  
delProgramList = new List<PA_Distribution__c>();            
}

public void addRow(){
    PayrollDistributionList.add(new PA_Distribution__c( Payroll_Authorization__c = PA.id));
}

public PageReference SavePA (){
    upsert PA; 
    upsert PayrollDistributionList;
    System.debug ('Upsert:' + PayrollDistributionList);
    delete delProgramList;
    System.debug ('Delete:' + delProgramList);
    return (new ApexPages.StandardController(PA)).view();
}

public void deleteRow(){


    rowID =ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RowID');

    For (Integer i=0; i<PayrollDistributionList.size(); i++){
    del= PayrollDistributionList[i];
        If (del.Id == rowID) {

            System.debug('Delete index: ' + i +  PayrollDistributionList[i]);
            PayrollDistributionList.remove(i);
            System.debug('List remaining is ' + PayrollDistributionList );

            If(del.Id <> null) delProgramList.add(del);
            System.debug ('Detele these: ' + delProgramList);
            break;
        }

    }
   }
```

}

My page:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Payroll_Authorization__c" sidebar="false" doctype="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="false" extensions="PayrollAuthorization_extn" applyBodyTag="true" lightningStylesheets="true">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
      .form-control {
          padding: 6px !important;
      }
      .btn-info {
        color: #fff!important;
        background-color: #5bc0de !important;
        border-color: #46b8da !important;
        background-image: none !important;
        padding: 8px 20px !important;
    }
     .table>thead>tr>th{
            vertical-align: top !important;
            text-align: left !important;
      }
      .table>tbody>tr>td{
            vertical-align: top !important;
            text-align: left !important;
      }
      .table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th {
            padding: 4px !important;
        }
        .list-group-item {
            padding: 6px 15px !important;
        }
  </style>
<apex:outputPanel id="scriptPanel">
    <script>

    function calctotal(){
        //   alert ("caltotal" + {!PayrollDistributionList.size}); 
          var tempRowTotal=0;
          var percenttotal= 0;
        for(var i=1; i<={!PayrollDistributionList.size};i++ ){

              tempRowTotal = ($('.wh'+i).val()!= null && $('.wh'+i).val() != '')?parseFloat($('.wh'+i).val()):0.0;
              percenttotal  += tempRowTotal;

            }
        return percenttotal;   
    }

    function calcRow(){
        //   alert ("calrow"); 

        var tempRowTotal=0;
         var percenttotal= 0;
           percenttotal= calctotal(); 
        for(var i=1; i<={!PayrollDistributionList.size};i++ ){  
          tempRowTotal = ($('.wh'+i).val()!= null && $('.wh'+i).val() != '')?parseFloat($('.wh'+i).val()):0.0;
          $('.wp' + i).text(((tempRowTotal * 100)/percenttotal).toFixed(2)+'%');
          $('.percenttotal').text(percenttotal.toFixed(2)+'%');     
          }
      }
        $(document).ready(function(){
              {
                  calcRow();
              }

      });    

    </script>
   </apex:outputPanel>
    <script>

    </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Payroll Distribution" id="er" >
        <div align="center" draggable="false" style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:4px"  >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!SavePA}" styleclass="btn btn-info" style="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}" styleclass="btn btn-info" immediate="true"/>
        </div>
        <div class="container-flud" style="font-size: 11.5px;">
            <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: -15px;">
                <ul class="list-group">      
                    <li class="list-group-item row" style="background-color: #702342;color: #fff;padding: 6px 10px;">
                        <h4 style="margin: 2px 0px;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bolder;">Payroll Authorization</h4>
                    </li>
                </ul>

      <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <ul class="list-group">      
            <li class="list-group-item row" style="background-color: #702342;color: #fff;padding: 6px 10px;">
                <h4 style="margin: 2px 0px;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bolder;">Payroll Distributions</h4>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered" >

                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Action
                    </th>    
                    <th>
                        Program
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Percentage worked
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Percentage total
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <apex:variable var="SelectedRowId" value="{!0}"/>
                    <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="index"/>  
                <apex:repeat value="{!PayrollDistributionList}" var="pd">
                    <tr>
                        <td> 
                            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRow}" immediate="true" reRender="er, scriptPanel" >
                                <apex:param name="RowID" value="{!pd.ID}"/>
                            </apex:commandButton>
                        </td>
                        <td><apex:inputfield value="{!pd.Program__c}"   style="Width: 50%"/></td>
                        <td ><apex:inputfield value="{!pd.Program_Percent__c}" styleClass="wh{!index}" onkeyup="calcRow()"/> </td>
                        <td Class="wp{!index}">
                            0%
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <apex:variable value="{!index+1}" var="index"/>

                </apex:repeat>
            </tbody>
        <tfoot> <tr>
            <th/>
            <th/>
                <th class="percenttotal">
                    0.0%
                </th>
                <th>
                    100.00%
                </th>
              </tr></tfoot>
          </table>
          </div>
        </div>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!addRow}" value="Add Program" immediate="true" reRender="er, scriptPanel"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>

    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: does the pageBlock with `id="er"` rerender successfully after the first row is deleted?

Comment: Yes, @cropredy, the pageblock does rerender successfully after the first delete; not successful after second delete and on.